# How do I dispatch contextmenu on click

Tags: angular

I'm using [ng2-contextmenu](https://github.com/ds82/ng2-contextmenu) which has a plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/vFzD58CDMhs6bggH168V?p=preview). I want to fire the same context menu on click as I'm getting when right-clicking.

I tried adding `(click)="rethrowContextMenu($event)"` to the element and defined that as:

```
rethrowContextMenu(e:MouseEvent):void{
    let evt = new MouseEvent('contextmenu',{bubbles:true});
    e.target.dispatchEvent(evt);
}
```

But it doesn't seem to trigger the context menu. Where am I going wrong?

[My Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/yBUgeesjXiv4twMTid7d?p=preview)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you take a look at source code you can notice global click handler:

```
@HostListener('document:click', [])
public onClick(): void {
    this.hide();
}
```

it means whenever you open dialog this handler will close it immediatelly. So you need to stop propagation your click event:

```
rethrowContextMenu(e:MouseEvent):void{
   let evt = new MouseEvent('contextmenu',{bubbles:true});
   e.target.dispatchEvent(evt);
   e.stopPropagation();
}
```

And you also need to pass `clientX` and `clientY` if you want to get right dialog position:

```
let evt = new MouseEvent('contextmenu', { 
  bubbles:true, 
  clientX: e.clientX, 
  clientY: e.clientY
});
```

**[Modified Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/n5Wu2DnK02aDu22mOxWd?p=preview)**

Comment: Haven't done event driven stuff in years, I totally forgot about needing to stop propagation when overriding actions like this. Thanks!